# How to add and immediately remove html element by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button and I want it to create or append an element when clicking it and after 1 sec it has to removed automatically
how I can do it

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
  $('#btnId').click(function(){
 $( "#divId" ).append( "<p id="test">Test</p>" );

     setTimeout(function(){
      $('#test').remove();
    }, 1000);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".abc").click(function(){
        $( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
        setTimeout(function(){$('p').remove();}, 1000);
      });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="inner">
 <input type="button" value="Click me" class="abc">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
   $('#btnId').click(function(){
     $( "#divToAppendId").append( "<span id="tempDivId">Element</span>" );

     setTimeout(function(){$('#tempDivId').remove();}, 1000);
  })
```

Here 1000 is a unit in milliseconds that means 1 second. So after 1-second element will be removed.